# How to Apply Behaviors on Xamarin Forms Platform

Tags: c, xamarin, bindableproperty

I want to numeric counterup/down animation my xamarin forms application. I found the code example [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/158746/number-from-to-animation)

But i haven't applied. How can i apply this behavior class Xamarin Forms label control.

I tried this code but not work.

```
 <Label x:Name="lblScore"  FontSize="24"  TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label.Behaviors>
                            <controls:NumericTextAnimationBehavior Value="{Binding Number}"/>
                        </Label.Behaviors>
                    </Label>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class ProfilePage : ContentPage
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = this;

        lblScore.Behaviors.Add(new NumericTextAnimationBehavior());
    }

    private void btnSetRandom_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Number = randomizer.Next(1, 9999).ToString();

        lblScore.Text = Number;

    }
}
```

It's not worked on my project. I want to apply counter animation for label.

Thank you for your supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched INotifyPropertyChanged pattern and solved it.

Model:

```
public class ScoreViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // boiler-plate
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    // props
    private string number;
    public string Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { SetField(ref number, value, "Number"); }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
public partial class ProfilePage : ContentPage
{
    ScoreViewModel scoreViewModel = new ScoreViewModel();
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lblScore.BindingContext = scoreViewModel;
    }

    private void btnSetRandom_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        scoreViewModel.Number = randomizer.Next(9999, 99999).ToString();

    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Label x:Name="lblScore"  FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Number}">
    <Label.Behaviors>
        <controls:NumericTextAnimationBehavior Value="{Binding Number}"/>
    </Label.Behaviors>
</Label>
```

If you want to deep learn about INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, look here ([Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist?answertab=active#tab-top))